# Infinitely many $n$ such that $\mu(n+1)=\cdots=\mu(n+k)$

Tags: number-theory

so my question is how to prove, given fixed $k>0$, that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\mu(n+1)=\cdots=\mu(n+k)$. My first guess was to suppose otherwise, but that didn't get me anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\mu$? The Mobius function?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\mu(m)$ is $0$ when $m$ is divisible by the square of  a prime. 
Thus you can try to find successive numbers all divisible by a a  square of some prime. 
This is not hard using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (take another prime for each number).

Comment: Ah, that's a good way to do it. Thank you.